# neo4j config entries in values file not updating neo4j.conf file

Tags: neo4j

I am trying update neo4j.config through values.yaml file "config" section. but my values are not being updated to neo4j.conf. below are the entries in config section of values file. Any help appreciated.

config:

dbms.memory.heap.initial_size: "28g"

dbms.memory.heap.max_size: "28g"

dbms.memory.pagecache.size: "55g"

dbms.security.procedures.allowlist: "apoc.coll.*,apoc.load.*,gds.*"

dbms.security.procedures.whitelist: "apoc.*,apoc.coll.*,apoc.load.*,gds.*"

dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted: "apoc.*,apoc.coll.*,apoc.load.*,gds.*"

Comment: what exactly is `values.yaml` file

Comment: while installing neo4j through helm charts, you can configure neo4j using values.yaml file which has all the configurable parameters. One of the block in that file is "config" which has all the "key: value" pairs which correspond to key=value in neo4j.conf.